# I cannot seem to run this program correctly

Tags: vb.net

keeps on saying press any key to continue i rechecked and followed as i learnt
but still no luck
pls help me correct this problem and sub main can be empty right???
           Num and Num 1 are global variables

```
Module Module1
Dim Num, Num1 As Integer

Sub Menu()
    Dim choice As Char

    While choice <> "Q" And choice <> "q"

        Console.Clear()

        Console.WriteLine("Simple Maths Calculator")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("enter choice: ")
        Console.WriteLine("enter (a) for add")
        Console.WriteLine("enter (b) for subtract")
        Console.WriteLine("enter (q) for quit")

        choice = Console.ReadLine()

        If choice <> "Q" And choice <> "q" Then
            TwoNumber()
        End If
        If choice = "A" Or "a" Then
            Add()
        ElseIf choice = "B" Or "b" Then
            Subtract()
        End If

    End While
End Sub
Sub Add()
    Console.WriteLine("the solution is: " & Num + Num1)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub Subtract()
    Console.WriteLine("the solution is: " & Num - Num1)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub TwoNumber()
    Console.WriteLine("enter first number")
    Num = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("enter second number")
    Num1 = Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub Main()
    Menu()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Main() is the entry point to console applications, your controlling logic needs to be there. In your case, it looks like you just need to add a call to Menu() inside Main()

Comment: You should turn Option Strict On. It will reduce the number of problems you'll encounter.

Comment: @soohoonigan thanks for that i did do it now it says conversion from string "a" to type 'Boolean' is not valid after i enter the choice and input both Num and Num1 it fails to do and show the calculation.

Comment: that is not how you compare. `if choice="A" or choice = "a" Then`  like you did with the Q. See the difference? Also, look at string.ToLower() this will solve having to check for both cases.

Comment: If you add "option strict on" and "option explicit on" like the_lotus suggested to the very top of your code file, visual studio will show you where the conversion errors are, why they are happening, and suggest ways to fix them when you hover over the errors

Comment: @CharlesMay its char and i think comparing it like that is possible

Comment: @soohoonigan how do i do that? and the video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA7pz9RZTug&t=1238s" shows that what i did is correct but...............

Comment: Ok, so what was that other than proof of what I just told you about comparing the two. Read up on the OR operator. It compares two booleans. choice="A" is a boolean result but "a" is not, so you would need to comapare with choice="a" too. Just like I stated. Option Strict On will show you these issues.

Comment: @CharlesMay ughhhh iam so done haha was so confused and tired after rewriting code couple of times that i missed it sorry for wasting ur time ill reconsider and recheck more before posting my problem again thank you.

Comment: You didn't waste my time as long as you learned something from this ;). Option strict will help you in the long run, no matter how daunting it seems when you first turn it on and see the error of your ways.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making sure that Main() calls Menu(), most of your problems arise from improper data-type conversions. Specifically, casting the user's ReadLine() input string into integers and checking Char equality. When comparing two things in .Net you generally want to you "OrElse" or "AndAlso", they behave differently and how (at least I) expect usual And/Or to behave. But if you check the chars properly, you don't even need and/or in this case. Adding "Option Strict On" and "Option Explicit On" to the top of your code file also helps point these errors out early so they can be addressed, and it's a good idea to always strongly type your code. Prevents conversion errors like what you experienced, and helps ensure your code doesn't behave in unpredictable ways. As you become more experienced, error handling is also a good idea to ensure that what a user inputs is a number, because even with my changes, if a user entered "J" or "1.1" instead of a number inside TwoNumber(), the program would crash or you'd lose the decimal point :( But for now, with a few simple changes to casts and comparisons applied, the code looks like this and should run fine

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Module Module1

    Dim Num, Num1 As Integer

    Sub Menu()
        Dim choice As Char

        While Not Char.ToLower(choice).Equals("q"c) 'check if choice is equal to Q/q

            Console.Clear()

            Console.WriteLine("Simple Maths Calculator")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("enter choice: ")
            Console.WriteLine("enter (a) for add")
            Console.WriteLine("enter (b) for subtract")
            Console.WriteLine("enter (q) for quit")

            choice = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Char)

            If Not Char.ToLower(choice).Equals("q"c) Then
                TwoNumber()
            End If
            If Char.ToLower(choice).Equals("a"c) Then
                Add()
            ElseIf Char.ToLower(choice).Equals("b"c) Then
                Subtract()
            End If

        End While
    End Sub
    Sub Add()
        Console.WriteLine("the solution is: " & Num + Num1)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Sub Subtract()
        Console.WriteLine("the solution is: " & Num - Num1)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Sub TwoNumber()
        Console.WriteLine("enter first number")
        Num = CInt(Console.ReadLine()) 'Convert the inputted string into an integer
        Console.WriteLine("enter second number")
        Num1 = CInt(Console.ReadLine()) 'Convert the inputted string into an integer
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Menu()
    End Sub

End Module
```